# as3 prevent random frame label from being selected twice in a row

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I wrote a small actionscript that basically tells a movie clip to go to and play a random frame listed within an array.  Here is the code:

```
function getRandomLabel(): String {

    var labels: Array = new Array("e1", "e2", "e3");
    var index: Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * labels.length);
    return labels[index];
}
mc.gotoAndStop(getRandomLabel());
```

The problem I am trying to resolve is to prevent that same random frame label from being selected twice in a row.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is ensure the current frame label is not chosen from the list you can do that by simply filtering out the current label from the array:

```
function getRandomLabel(currentLabel:String):String {
    var labels:Array = ["e1", "e2", "e3"];
    var currentIndex:int = labels.indexOf(currentLabel);
    if (currentIndex > -1) 
        labels.splice(currentIndex, 1);
    var index:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * labels.length);
    return labels[index];
}

mc.gotoAndStop(getRandomLabel(mc.currentLabel));
```

---

In fact, if all you want to do is go to *any* frame label other than the current one, you can just use `MovieClip/currentLabels` and make it a re-usable function for any `MovieClip`:

```
function gotoRandomFrameLabel(mc:MovieClip):void {
    var labels:Array = mc.currentLabels.filter(function(frame:FrameLabel, ...args):Boolean {
        return frame.name != mc.currentLabel;
    });
    var index:int = Math.random() * labels.length;
    mc.gotoAndStop(labels[index].frame);
}

gotoRandomFrameLabel(mc);
gotoRandomFrameLabel(other_mc);
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to shuffle the array every `n` calls to `getRandomLabel` with `n` being the length of the `labels` array. When you shuffle, make sure the most recently used label isn't the first item in the array.

```
// this array can be of any length, and the solution should still work
var labels:Array = ["e1","e2","e3"]; 
var count:int = labels.length;
labels.sort(randomSort);

function getRandomLabel(): String {
    count--;

    var randomLabel:String = labels.shift();
    labels.push(randomLabel);

    // when the counter reaches 0, it's time to reshuffle
    if(count == 0)
    {
        count = labels.length;

        labels.sort(randomSort);
        // ensure that the next label isn't the same as the current label
        if(labels[0] == randomLabel)
        {
            labels.push(labels.shift());
        }
    }

    return randomLabel;
}

// this function will "shuffle" the array
function randomSort(a:*, b:*):int 
{
    return Math.random() > .5 ? 1 : -1;
}
```